# drupal module path and view path collision

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

In Drupal 7 I created a custom module. With the menu hook I defined the following path:

```
  $items['reports/%'] = [
    'page callback' => 'report_area_page_ajax',
    'page arguments' => [1],
    'access callback' => true, // todo: set this
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'depathlivery callback' => 'report_ajax_get_ajax'
  ];
```

Next, I've created a page in Views (latest version 7.x-3.11) with the path 'reports/%/archive'.

There seems to be some kind of collision as I get these errors when 'reports/%/archive' is requested:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in element_children() (line 6525 of /home/user/domains/domain/public_html/includes/common.inc).
Warning: Illegal string offset '#children' in drupal_render() (line 5982 of /home/user/domains/domain/public_html/includes/common.inc).
Warning: Illegal string offset '#children' in drupal_render() (line 5992 of /home/user/domains/domain/public_html/includes/common.inc).
Warning: Illegal string offset '#children' in drupal_render() (line 6030 of /home/user/domains/domain/public_html/includes/common.inc).
Warning: Illegal string offset '#printed' in drupal_render() (line 6037 of /home/user/domains/domain/public_html/includes/common.inc).
```

When I configure the view with some other path (for example bla/%) the view page can be requested without any errors.

What could be causing this?

Comment: you must use different urls for your project. you must change your menu callback or view path, both must not have same "reports/%"

Comment: The path is not the same! "reports/%" and "reports/%/archive" are different, so this should be possible.

Comment: I created a module and a simple view with url, and I get no errors. what you use for contexual filters in your view? is it differs from your module?